# Soa design for multiple data source

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, architecture, soa

In a way to improve my service oriented architecture understanding, I am building a system to manage the follow up of clients.

**Clients api**

Like you see , It could have an infinite numbers of clients web services. Theirs roles are only to retrieve client data. Because they are different, they do not share any common communication interface and do not return data in a same format.

**ClientToFollowAdapter**

This is the web service that will know how to consume different clients web service, manage the authentication with them. Another role will be to receive data from any client api
and parse it in a common format consumable by the follow up web service itself

**The question:**

Is it an known pattern and what do you think about it?

[image: soa diagram]

Comment: Essentially you are creating a facade to wrap the other services into one generic API. Yeah it is all good. Just remember your `ClientToFollowUp` API should be abstracted away from the providing client api's. That is going to be the hard part.

Comment: An integration framework or an esb can replace clienttofollwoadapter. I dont see an issue with your approach though.

Comment: Thank @Namphibian Its exactly what the ClientToFollowApi is at the moment a facade. However my concern was more about the "Adapter" one, wondering if is the good pattern to use. Looks like the esb one fit my need

Comment: Thank @ techuser , I never heard about esb pattern for soa design I just read about the concept and the implementtion and look like it does what "clientToFollowAdapter" does. I will prefer esp to it.